# How to get character's Unicode in Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: ruby, unicode, ruby-1.8

To get character's Unicode in Ruby 1.9.2, I use `ord`:

```
"я".ord       # => 1103     (It's a Russian letter)
```

How could I get the Unicode in **Ruby 1.8.7** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I found this nice solution:

```
"я".unpack('U')[0]     # => 1103
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use my [`backports`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem. Running with Ruby 1.8.7 (and option `-KU` to setup `$KCODE` for utf-8):

```
require "rubygems"
require "backports/1.8.7/string/ord"
"я".ord # => 1103
```